# Subset a 3d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have checked the numpy documentation but some of the indexing still eludes me. I have a numpy array such that its shape is (40000, 432) and its looks something like:

```
arr = [[1,2,3......431,432],
       [1,2,3......431,432],
       [1,2,3......431,432],
       ....................
       [1,2,3......431,432]'
       [1,2,3......431,432]]
```

I wanted to subset each array over a range (ie. 20-50) so that the shape will be (40000, 30) and it will look like:

```
subarr = [[20,21,22...48,49,50],
          [20,21,22...48,49,50],
          [20,21,22...48,49,50],
          .....................
          [20,21,22...48,49,50]]
```

Everything I try either returns me an error or gives me the shape (30, 432) which is not what I need. How do I subset a 2d array along the axis I want to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `numpy` [slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

```
arr = np.zeros((40000, 432))
subarr = arr[:, 20:50]
print(subarr.shape)
```

**Output**

```
(40000L, 30L)
```

The `L` in the shape output indicates that the integer is of Python type `long`.

Comment: Ah, I see I wasn't using the comma correctly. I assume that this references all of the first axis?